# Android motion layout not working accordingly

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-transitions, android-motionlayout

I am new to `motionlayout` and been following various tutorials online like [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/getting-started-with-motion-layout-android-tutorials) to get an understanding of how it works. From a nutshell I have come to know it basically animates `constraintSets`, you have a `start` and `end` `constraintSet` which you can further customize with `KeyFrameSets`. I have this layout

[image]

I want to mimic `Lyft's bottom sheet`

[image]

With my layout the `Where are you going` button is suppose to slowly fade out as the search destination `textInputs` fade in. The `recyclerview` at the bottom is suppose to hold saved `addresses`, it will not be affected. I tried this implementation using a standard `bottomsheet` but had challenges with the animation, it had this weird `flickering` so I decided to use a `MotionLayout` with a normal view.

My `bottomsheet` layout is as follows

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardChooseAddressBottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearanceRoundedLargeTopCorners">



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/swipeUpHandle"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_swipe_up_handle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/hiThere"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:text="@string/hi_there"
            android:textAppearance="@style/h6_headline"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/swipeUpHandle"
            />


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:letterSpacing="0.0"
            android:text="@string/where_are_you_going"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textAppearance="@style/subtitle1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            app:iconTint="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hiThere"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceRoundedMediumAllCorners" />



        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/addressViews"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSearch">



            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputOrigin"
                style="@style/textInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
                android:hint="@string/search_destination"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtOrigin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/subtitle1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputDestination"
                style="@style/textInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
                android:hint="@string/search_destination"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/inputOrigin">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtDestination"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/subtitle1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerAddresses"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/addressViews"
            tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

And my parent layout where I include the `bottomsheet` is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/taxi_bottomsheet_scene"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    <include
        layout="@layout/choose_destination_bottom_sheet_layout"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

And finally my `taxi_bottomsheet_scene` motion scene is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/expanded"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/collapsed"
        app:duration="1000">

        <OnSwipe
            app:touchAnchorId="@+id/btnSearch"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top"
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"/>


    </Transition>


    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/cardChooseAddressBottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />



        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/addressViews"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"/>


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0"/>

    </ConstraintSet>




    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/cardChooseAddressBottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"  />


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/addressViews"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.0"/>



        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.0"/>
    </ConstraintSet>





</MotionScene>
```

When I launch this app I cannot get the bottomsheet to slide up, it simply does not respond in any way. One thing I noticed though is after adding the `app:layoutDescription="@xml/taxi_bottomsheet_scene"`attribute, the bottom sheet size changed to what I had specified in the `constraintSetStart` but the `addressViews` view did not.

So my layout looks like

[image: parent layout after attaching it to the motion scene]

So my question is, where I am going wrong for my bottomsheet not to respond to my `swipes` and `addressViews` to disappear in the initial state?

Comment: did u fix it? I'm also working on the same situation. But not with the MotionLayout

Comment: Yes I did. I will post the answer shortly.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Appreciate it.

Comment: @shine_joseph I managed the same effect with both `MotionLayout` and `coordinatorlayout`. MotionLayout was making the `MapFragment` flicker but the `CoordinatorLayout` approach is not. Which one should I provide?

Comment: You can provide whichever works best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work, both with `MotionLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout`. I will only post the `Coordinator` solution as it is long and I do not have the time, if someone needs it, comment and I will post.

I created 3 layouts, `1. The main layout with the map`, `2. Top bar with the to and from address EditTexts` and `3. The bottom layout` that slides up and reveals the top bar.

**Solution 1 using CoordinatorLayout**

1. The topbar

   ```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/medium_margin"
       app:layout_scrollFlags="noScroll">


       <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
           android:id="@+id/topToolBar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />


       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:id="@+id/addressViews"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topToolBar">


           <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
               android:id="@+id/imgOrigin"
               android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
               android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_margin"
               android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/medium_margin"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/inputOrigin"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/inputOrigin"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/inputOrigin"
               app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_origin"
               app:tint="@color/colorAccent" />


           <View
               android:layout_width="2dp"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
               android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
               android:background="@drawable/accent_to_color_primary_dark__negative_90_gradient"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgDestination"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgOrigin"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imgOrigin"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgOrigin" />

           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
               android:id="@+id/inputOrigin"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
               android:hint="@string/pick_up_location"
               android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgOrigin"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                   android:id="@+id/edtOrigin"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@color/white"
                   android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                   android:singleLine="true"
                   android:textAppearance="@style/subtitle1" />

           </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


           <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
               android:id="@+id/imgDestination"
               android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
               android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_margin"
               android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/medium_margin"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/inputDestination"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/inputDestination"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/inputDestination"
               app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_destination"
               app:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
               android:id="@+id/inputDestination"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
               android:hint="@string/search_destination"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgDestination"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/inputOrigin">

               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                   android:id="@+id/edtDestination"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@color/white"
                   android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                   android:singleLine="true"
                   android:textAppearance="@style/subtitle1" />

           </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
   ```
2. The bottom layout that acts like a bottom sheet

   ```
   <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/cardChooseAddressBottomSheet"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
   app:behavior_hideable="false"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">


   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/swipeUpHandle"
           android:layout_width="35dp"
           android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_swipe_up_handle"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


       <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
           android:id="@+id/hiThere"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/hi_there"
           android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:textAppearance="@style/h6_headline"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/swipeUpHandle" />


       <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
           android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
           style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="60dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
           android:letterSpacing="0.0"
           android:text="@string/where_are_you_going"
           android:textAllCaps="false"
           android:textAppearance="@style/subtitle1"
           android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
           app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
           app:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
           app:iconSize="@dimen/medium_icon"
           app:iconTint="@color/colorAccent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hiThere"
           app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceRoundedMediumAllCorners" />


       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recyclerAddresses"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSearch" />


       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recyclerSearchAddresses"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:visibility="gone"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnSearch" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

   </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
   ```
3. And finally the two layouts included in my map layout

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/coordinator"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">


           <fragment
               android:id="@+id/map"
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.67"
               app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/imgMapCenter"
               android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xlarge_margin"
               android:visibility="invisible"
               android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/map"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/map"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/map"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/map"
               app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_destination" />
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


       <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
           android:id="@+id/fabMyLocation"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
           app:fabSize="mini"
           app:layout_anchor="@id/cardChooseAddressBottomSheet"
           app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right"
           app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_origin"
           app:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
       <include layout="@layout/taxi_fragment_set_destination_top_bar" />

       <include layout="@layout/taxi_fragment_bottom_sheet_addresses_layout" />

   </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```

And my fragment

```
   final private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback addressBottomSheetCallBack = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                    break;

                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                    break;

                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                    if (!allPermissionsGranted())
                        requestForLocationPermissions();
                    topAddressBar.setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
                     fabMyLocation.hide();
                    break;

                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                    if (!allPermissionsGranted())
                        requestForLocationPermissions();
                    topAddressBar.setVisibility(Visibility.INVISIBLE);
                    fabMyLocation.show();
                    break;

                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                    break;

                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED:
                    break;
            }
        }



   BottomSheetBehavior addressBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(cardChooseAddressBottomSheet);

      topAddressBar.post(() -> {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) cardChooseAddressBottomSheet.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = ((Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels + (int) utils.percentageOf(62, btnSearch.getMeasuredHeight())) - topAddressBar.getMeasuredHeight());
        });


        addressBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight((int) utils.percentageOf(29, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels), true);
        addressBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);


        topToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(view12 -> {
            if (addressBottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                utopAddressBar.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                addressBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            } else
                Navigation.findNavController(view12).navigateUp();
        });

        addressBottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(addressBottomSheetCallBack);
```

Notice am using `INVISIBLE` instead of `GONE` on the `topAddressBar`? that is because everytime I called `GONE` the layout would ideally `recalculate` according to my assumption and the map would flicker, to stop that I had to use invisible as the layout does not shrink instead it still takes up the same space but just not visible.

Also notice I am adding padding `cardChooseAddressBottomSheet.getLayoutParams()` this is because I need the Sheet not to go too deep underneath the `topAddressBar` as not to hide my recyclerview content. The current padding makes sure the recyclerview is fully visible and everything else on top of it is underneath the `topAddressBar`

Comment: Hi, can you share the MotionLayout solution? Or if your code at github you can share github link also. Thank you @Astonio

Comment: Check out https://github.com/serbelga/Material-Motion-Samples @K.tas

Comment: Hi, can you share the updated code it would be helpful